# Unexpected error - Angular 1 + Meteor 1.6

Tags: meteor

I am getting this error on the client side in browser web application.

> Unexpected error.

This appears in a totally white blank page in the browser on the top left corner when I access my web application.

It appears occasionally. There is no error in the Meteor Server Console or in the browser console. It can't be reproduced either.

Whenever this error appears, none of my client apps (Android, iOS, web app) work, when they are connected to this specific server. The server shows that it's running but it does not. When I restart Meteor Server, then it starts working fine, I get this error once in about two weeks, I don’t know what is causing this error, or how to debug this.

Any idea what is causing this issue? This is really critical, I have my Live Application running, and it should not crash like this. Please provide me with some solution or a way to debug. Thanks

Also are there any logs on my Meteor App which I can check? Plus I am running this App on staging with `--production` flag.

Comment: Does this only occur in the staging environment?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I have the staging and live app but both are running on --production. Issue faced on both sides, even on the local server.

Comment: Do you have a chance to use a built version in your staging environment for a while? If so you could check if the error happens there as well plus with a stricter execution leading maybe to an understandable error. I have faced this error some times ago but only in dev mode and it disappeared after restart. However I had never such an error in my stage or production using a built release.

Comment: @Jankapunkt What do you mean by built release?

Comment: Using [meteor build](https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#custom-deployment) and run it as a node application instead of using the [--production flag](https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#never-use-production-flag).

Comment: @Jankapunkt Can I try this on a local server ?

Comment: should run on any machine that has a proper node environment installed. Maybe you check out the custom deployment guide: https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#custom-deployment

Comment: @Jankapunkt Ok i just tried meteor build, but I am getting this error now: MongoError: failed to connect to server [192.168.100.2:9005] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.100.2:9005]

Comment: For this you may open a new question as I never saw this and can't really help you on that.

Comment: @Jankapunkt Alright, Thanks for the help, much appreciated